# Spring Cloud Config Server Setting Datasource Dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-jdbc, application.properties, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a small doubt. I need to connect Spring Cloud Config Server with JDBC Backend. But the credentials to connect to the DB aren’t readily available. The real password has to be retrieved from Cyberark using a nickname and I have relevant Java Code for the same. I need a mechanism where this deciphered Password and Username can be used for setting the datasource of the Spring Cloud Config Server. Is this possible?

Comment: How is your application to be deployed? You could provide the JDBC details (username, etc) to the application as external environment variables or properties. In that way the provision of the values becomes a problem resolved outside the code itself and dependent on the environment the application is run in. If it were a container application (for example) then getting and setting the values is something you could do in a CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: @JohnXF it's to be deployed via a CI/CD pipeline only, but the values have to be not just obtained but also processed. I need to resolve my password using a special function that is written in Java Code

Comment: some more details on what you are trying to connect to and what you are doing to the password might help elicit an answer from someone familiar with the problem. If you externalise the spring properties into a file or ENV variables, then you could have some code pre-process some values to create the external values your actual spring application with use on startup.

Comment: @JohnXF I'm trying to connect to mssql backend and use it as a datasource for the config server. Imagine I want to do some decryption of the password thro Java Code. It's not a standard procedure. For the sake of simplicity let's assume I have a mapping of passwords for relevant username in my java code. I am only allowed to provide Username. It'll resolve PW by itself